# Pandas Installation on PyPy

Tags: python, pandas, linux, pip, pypy

I've seen a number of questions here referring to particular package installations on PyPy and have tried a number of them. However, I haven't found a suitable answer to my question. So, the point is the following:

I am trying to install pandas on pypy (under Linux OS). I have followed the below steps:

```py
conda create -n pypy pypy

conda activate pypy

pypy -m pip install --upgrade numpy --user
```

so far no problem. When I use:

```
pypy -m pip install --upgrade pandas --user
```

or

```
pypy -m pip install --upgrade pandas
```

installation fails with this error message: " ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects".

I should say that the same installation procedure works perfectly fine on Mac.

I have also tried installation through conda. Although it doesn't fail while installing, however, when I import pandas, it raises this error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval'".

I would appreciate your solutions. Thanks!

Comment: What version of PyPy? There are binary packages available for pypy3.8 and pypy3.9

Comment: It is 3.8. Can you please give me the correct links? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to use scientific python (pandas, scipy, ...) with PyPy 3.8 and 3.9 is via conda, You can [get started](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-pypy-as-an-interpreter) with

```
$ conda create -c conda-forge -n my-pypy-env pypy python=3.8
$ conda activate my-pypy-env
$ conda install -c conda-forge pandas
```

Note that until [HPy](https://hpyproject.org/) becomes used in cython, you should not expect PyPy to speed up code that heavily uses c-extensions built with cython (like pandas). You can read why [here](https://www.pypy.org/posts/2018/09/inside-cpyext-why-emulating-cpython-c-8083064623681286567.html)